# object x deleting itself from a List<x>

Tags: c#, list

Suppose you have a list of objects 
and the object has a Destroy method and one of its job is to remove 
itself from the list. Remembering your index number won't do it because 
some other object may have been removed which will change the index 
number.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why is its job to remove itself?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Index numbers aren't a big deal in lists either.

Comment: You can pass an object to `List.Remove`, you don't need an index number.

Comment: The object x is a very complex structure and the Destroy method does many consequential things and, as its last act, it would be nice if it could remove itself from the list.

Comment: @Dortimer I didn't know you could do that. Doesn't this mean you can say this.Remove(); inside my Destroy method? I'm a lifelong C programmer trying to learn C#.

Comment: @BingBang I think you'd probably be better off having code outside the list managing `.Remove()`'s and so on. I believe `.Remove()` calls the object's destructor, so you could probably handle whatever you need in there.

One note: if you're looping through a list with `foreach` you can't make modifications to the list. So you'll have to use a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: @Blorgbeard So in the Destroy object I can say List.Remove(this); ?

Comment: @Blorgbeard method, not object

Comment: If it holds a reference to the list, then yes, it can do that. I do think the design is a bit smelly though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, well, I have a ways to go.